# Stack Build error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

I am trying to run `stack build` and get the following errors:

```
bartosz $ stack setup
The GHC located at /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin/ghc failed to compile a sanity check. Please see:

    http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/install_and_upgrade/

for more information. Exception was:
Received ExitFailure 1 when running
Raw command: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin/ghc /private/var/folders/rj/vrrtj8094qb8gf4ky_r_mxq80000gn/T/stack-sanity-check4255/Main.hs -no-user-package-db
Run from: /private/var/folders/rj/vrrtj8094qb8gf4ky_r_mxq80000gn/T/stack-sanity-check4255/
Standard output:

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /private/var/folders/rj/vrrtj8094qb8gf4ky_r_mxq80000gn/T/stack-sanity-check4255/Main.hs, /private/var/folders/rj/vrrtj8094qb8gf4ky_r_mxq80000gn/T/stack-sanity-check4255/Main.o )
Linking /private/var/folders/rj/vrrtj8094qb8gf4ky_r_mxq80000gn/T/stack-sanity-check4255/Main ...
Standard error:

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-nopie' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_closure, _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding1_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding4_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding6_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_info , _hs_iconv_open , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding9_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding12_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding7_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding13_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_info , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding11_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding14_bytes , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding15_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding2_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding3_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding8_closure , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding10_bytes , _hs_iconv_close , _hs_iconv , _base_GHCziIOziEncodingziIconv_iconvEncoding5_closure )
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_open in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_open)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _hs_iconv_close in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(iconv.o)
     (maybe you meant: _hs_iconv_close)
  "_locale_charset", referenced from:
      _localeEncoding in libHSbase-4.11.1.0.a(PrelIOUtils.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
`gcc' failed in phase `Linker'. (Exit code: 1)
```

Here is the output from `stack path`:

```
stack-root: /Users/evanzamir/.stack
project-root: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz
config-location: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/stack.yaml
bin-path: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin/stack:/usr/local/smlnj-110.77/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:/Users/evanzamir/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/smlnj-110.77/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin/jitsu :/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/share/npm/bin
programs: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx
compiler-exe: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin/ghc
compiler-bin: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin
compiler-tools-bin: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/compiler-tools/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/bin
local-bin: /Users/evanzamir/.local/bin
extra-include-dirs: 
extra-library-dirs: 
snapshot-pkg-db: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb
local-pkg-db: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb
global-pkg-db: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/lib/ghc-8.4.4/package.conf.d
ghc-package-path: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb:/Users/evanzamir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/pkgdb:/Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx/ghc-8.4.4/lib/ghc-8.4.4/package.conf.d
snapshot-install-root: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4
local-install-root: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4
snapshot-doc-root: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/snapshots/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/doc
local-doc-root: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/doc
dist-dir: .stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-2.2.0.1
local-hpc-root: /Users/evanzamir/Code/Haskell/bartosz/.stack-work/install/x86_64-osx/lts-12.17/8.4.4/hpc
local-bin-path: /Users/evanzamir/.local/bin
ghc-paths: /Users/evanzamir/.stack/programs/x86_64-osx
```

Been trying to figure this out all day. I'm on OS X Mojave 14.1. I've tried installing stack using the script, Brew, directly from the binary, and even the Haskell Platform installer, and all are giving me errors.

Comment: Have you tried installing [libiconv](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libiconv) ?

Comment: @bergey No I haven't tried that. Is that something that is required but not documented anywhere? Also, is this necessary on OS X?

Comment: Those are errors from the linker, and I think the functions it's looking for are provided by `libiconv`.  It's one of those problems that I only run into every few years, when setting up a new computer, so I'm not sure which OSes require it or how I figured this out.  I have `libiconv` installed on my Mac, so I assume I installed it in response to errors like these.